# Translate LINQ to sql statement

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to translate LINQ expression tree to SQL statement and I don't want to write my own code for this.

Example:

```
var query = from c in Customers
where c.Country == "UK" &&
      c.City == "London"
select c);
```

To

```
SELECT ... FROM Customers AS c WHERE c.Country = "UK" AND c.City = "London"
```

I know `DataContext.Log`, but I want to use:

```
query.ToSqlStatementString()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
CustomDataContext dc = new CustomDataContext();
IQueryable<Customer> query =
  from c in dc.Customer
  where c.Country == "UK"
  select c;
//
string command = dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText;
```

Comment: It's ok:)... but I need opened db connection to get this work:) (I don't know why:))... do you know how other way?

Answer (score 12):

Amy B's answer gets you what you want, but there is the hidden cost of requiring a database connection. The reason this is done is to determine the SQL server version by asking the server itself. To avoid this, you should use this code snippet:

```
/// <summary>
/// Through reflection (HACK) this sets the MS impl of LINQ-to-SQL to not attempt connection to the database just
/// to determine the SQL server version running to tailor the SQL query to.
/// </summary>
private static void hack_SetLINQ2SQLProviderMode(CustomDataContext db)
{
    object provider = hack_GetLINQ2SQLProvider(db);

    provider
        .GetType()
        .GetField("mode", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .SetValue(provider, 2);
}

private static object hack_GetLINQ2SQLProvider(CustomDataContext db)
{
    return db
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Provider", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .GetValue(_db, new object[0]);
}
```

Call `hack_SetLINQ2SQLProviderMode(db)` where `db` is your `DataContext` derived class.

That will set the `mode` field of MS's implementation of LINQ-to-SQL's IQueryProvider to tell it you mean to generate SQL code for MS SQL Server 2005, indicated by `SetValue(provider, 2)`. Use `1` for MS SQL Server 2000 or `3` for MS SQL Server 2008.

This means that since the `mode` field is set, the implementation no longer needs to open the SQL connection to the database and you can now work completely offline.

Please note that this is using full-trust reflection, from what I understand. You should only use this approach in an environment that you control and that fully trusts your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ToQueryString()` working for me.

```
var query = your_link_query;
Console.WriteLine(query.ToQueryString());
```

See the working illustration.
[image]