# How do you generate SQL using LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq, postgresql

I want to be able to take a LINQ statement like this.

```
var User = from u in Users
           where u.UserID == 7
           select u.UserName;
```

And have it generate SQL like this.

`SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE Users.UserID = 7`

I know LINQ TO SQL does this but I don't want all that added xml mapping and generated code.
Obviously this is possible since LINQ TO SQL does it but how does it do it?

**Update**

Other reason why I don't want to use LINQ to SQL is because I want to use it for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550826/translate-linq-to-sql-statement

Comment: The answer uses LINQ to SQL which is not what I want.

Comment: DbLinq is an open-source LINQ provider for PostgreSQL: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

Comment: DbLinq looks very promising. Is it production ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there doesn't seem to be an open source production ready LINQ to PostgreSQL library.
So since this is a new project I'm going to use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) with [MongoDB-CSharp](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp#readme) as my LINQ driver.
It does everything I need it too with the added benefit of not having to worry about schemas and stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

So, you should download LinqPad:

http://www.linqpad.net/

This will give you some nice information about what LINQ is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want one of the approaches suggested here- http://www.thereforesystems.com/view-query-generate-by-linq-to-sql/

But you could consider instead using Entity Framework with Postgres SQL http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Comment: The first one uses LINQ to SQL and the second one is a product. Looking for an open source answer or some steps on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Devart LinqConnect - http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/. It supports PostgreSQL and allows you to define flexible templates for sql generation.